# How do I add a string to a symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am still learning Ruby and was using this code on my RoR app:

```
<title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title):"" %> - Mysite</title>
```

I want to add another static word, `" - "` or `" | "`, in `yield(:title)`. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<title><%= content_for?(:title) ? "#{yield(:title)} -" : "" %> - Mysite</title>
```